# Python json dictionary to array

Tags: python, arrays, json, dictionary

I am having some trouble understanding json dictionary and array. I have a script that is scraping information from a website.

models.txt is just a list of model numbers such as

```
30373
30374
30375
```

and json_descriptions.txt is a list of the keys I want

```
sku
price
listprice
issoldout
```

The code is:

```
import urllib
import re
import json

modelslist = open("models.txt").read()
modelslist = modelslist.split("\n")
descriptionlist = open("json_descriptions.txt").read()
descriptionlist = descriptionlist.split("\n")

for model in modelslist:
    htmltext = urllib.urlopen("http://dx.com/p/GetProductInfoRealTime?skus="+model)
    htmltext = json.load(htmltext)
    if htmltext['success'] == True:
        def get_data(dict_index, key):
            return htmltext[u"data"][dict_index][key]
        for description in descriptionlist:
           info = description, (get_data(0,description))
           print info
    else:
       print "product does not exist"
```

If I print out info I get:

```
sku 30373
price 9.10
listprice 17.62
issoldout False
```

so that means info[0] is:

```
sku
price
listprice
issoldout
```

and info[1] is:

```
30373
9.10
17.62
False
```

I would like to know if there is a way that I can have this:
loop 1 = `['sku','30373','price','4.90','listprice','0','issoldout','False']`
loop 2 = `['sku','30374','price','10.50','listprice','0','issoldout','False']`

`info[0] = sku` `info[1] = 30373` `info[2] = price` `info[3] = 4.90` `info[4] = listprice` `info[5] = 0` `info[6] = issoldout` `info[7] = False` and then repeat that with a new list for the next loop through.

I have tried using `info = json.dumps(info)` but that just gives `info[0] = [[[[` and `info[1] = """"` `info[2] = spli` and so on

Comment: Are you sure this is an array and not a dictionary?  The way you're using it suggests the latter.

Comment: yeah, my fault... still learning, I'll edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
info = []
for model in modelslist:
    htmltext = urllib.urlopen("http://dx.com/p/GetProductInfoRealTime?skus="+model)
    htmltext = json.load(htmltext)
    if htmltext['success'] == True:
        def get_data(dict_index, key):
            return htmltext[u"data"][dict_index][key]
        for description in descriptionlist:
            info.append(description)
            info.append(get_data(0,description))
print info
```